# Can bind9 (DNS server) be hooked? or create extension?

Tags: linux, dns, named, bind9

e.g. bind9 server is running at 127.0.0.1:

```
$ dig mytest.com @127.0.0.1 

# got this result: 
mytest.com  A 1.1.1.1
```

Can I create an extension for bind9 to monitor the traffice?  ( e.g. know there is a client from IP 2.2.2.2 queried this domain `mytest.com`, and if the domain `mytest.com` is in the blacklist, this extension can do something )

POE gave me an example but it does not work: ( I think POE is cheating me ... )

```
// bind_extensions.py

from isc import dns

# 黑名单列表，包含需要拦截的IP地址
blacklist = ["1.2.3.4"]

class BlacklistExtension:
    def __init__(self, zone_name):
        self.zone_name = zone_name

    def pre_resolve(self, qname, qtype, client_ip):
        if qtype == dns.rdatatype.A and client_ip in blacklist:
            # 如果请求的A记录在黑名单中，返回"未找到"
            return dns.message.make_response(dns.message.make_query(qname, qtype), rcode=dns.rcode.NXDOMAIN)

        return None

    def post_resolve(self, qname, qtype, response, client_ip):
        # 记录请求的A记录和客户端IP地址
        if qtype == dns.rdatatype.A and response.rcode() == dns.rcode.NOERROR:
            for rrset in response.answer:
                if rrset.rdtype == dns.rdatatype.A:
                    for rdata in rrset:
                        print(f"Request for '{qname}' A record from {client_ip}. Answer: {rdata.address}")

# 扩展点定义
extensions = [BlacklistExtension("test.com")]
```

Comment: I don't think BIND has any built-in extension or customization ability.

Comment: But it's open source software, so you can branch it and add your changes.